# Executing Code on a Certain Date?

Tags: c++, date, time

Basically, I want to create a program that will check the month, the day and the year and will execute code if both the month and the day criteria is met.

For example, let's say the date was July 8th, 2016.

Let's say I had some code that simply wanted the program to output "Hello world!" on this date.

I would want this code to execute on July 8, 2016 and no other date. How would I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To *run* your program at a certain time, you have to rely on external tools such as `cron` or the Windows task scheduler. A program cannot run itself if it's not already running :-)

If your code *is* running and you just want it to delay action until some specific time, that's what all the stuff in the `ctime` header is for.

You can use `time()` and `localtime()` to get your local time into a `struct tm`, then examine the fields to check if some specific time is current. If so, do your action. If not, loop around and try again (with a suitable delay if needed).

By way of example, here's a program that outputs the time but only on five-second boundaries:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    time_t now;
    struct tm *tstr;

    // Ensure first one is printed.

    int lastSec = -99;

    // Loop until time call fails, hopefully forever.

    while ((now = time(0)) != (time_t)-1) {
        // Get the local time into a structire.

        tstr = localtime(&now);

        // Print, store seconds if changed and multiple of five.

        if ((lastSec != tstr->tm_sec) && ((tstr->tm_sec % 5) == 0)) {
            cout << asctime(tstr);
            lastSec = tstr->tm_sec;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `std::this_thread::sleep_until(time_to_execute);`  where `time_to_execute` is a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.

Now the question becomes:  How do you set the `system_clock::time_point` to the correct value?

[Here is a free, open-source library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) for easily setting a `system_clock::time_point` to a specific date.  Using it would look like:

```
using namespace date;
std::this_thread::sleep_until(sys_days{jul/8/2016});
```

This would trigger at 2016-07-08 00:00:00 UTC.  If you would rather trigger based on your local time, or some arbitrary time zone, [here is a companion library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) to accomplish that.

You can also drop down to the C API and set a `std::tm`'s field values, convert that to a `time_t` and then convert that to a `system_clock::time_point`.  It is uglier, more error prone, and doesn't require a 3rd party library.